# PHP Warning missing Argument 1 for __()

Tags: php, l10n

I am getting this error in my server error logs:

```
[Thu Dec 11 10:06:30 2014] [error] [client 11.111.111.111] PHP Warning:  Missing argument 1 for __(), called in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/public_html/wp-content/themes/mysite_v2.2/functions-cpt-projects.php on line 15 and defined in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.org/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php on line 146, referer: http://www.mysite.org/wp-admin/edit.php
```

I've never encountered this before and I'm wondering what might be causing it. The line of code it refers to in the `l10n.php` file is:

```
function __( $text, $domain = 'default' ) {
    return translate( $text, $domain );
}
```

I'm wondering if anyone knows how I might go about debugging this? I read somewhere that it could be related to a plugin and to disable them one by one to find out if the issue is resolved but this has not worked for me as of yet.

Comment: PHP errors are off-topic as they are not specific to WordPress. Also, note that the error message says what is causing the problem: you are not providing the first argument that is required by the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you get this error if you passed empty string or did not pass any argument to the `__()` function.

You should check where you've used the `__()` function and check what value is being passed as argument.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. 
The issue was with a Custom Post Type and the solution was that the [_x()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_x/) translation function needed context (the 'missing argument') for a single word that has multiple meanings.

Example: Custom Post Type "Members" threw this error:

> Warning: Missing argument 2 for _x(), called in
>   /wp-content/plugins/my-cpt/posttypes.php on line 29 and defined in
>   /Users/SITE-NAME/Sites/THEME-NAME/wp-includes/l10n.php on line 294

---

Without context, my [Custom Post Type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) looked like this:

---

[image: Custom Post Type without Context]

The 'Members' name/s were throwing all the errors because without **context**, (*the second argument taken by the [_x()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_x/) function*), translators might not know which Member I was referring to.

---

For Example:

- Member - Someone or something that belongs to a group or an organization?
- Member - A part of a structure?
- Member - A body part, such as an arm or a leg?

  ---

  So I added context:

---

[image: Custom Post Type with context]

And the error messages went away.

Comment: Though it’s optional it is allways good to set the third parameter ($domain) using a short unique custom string. That helps to differentiate when using for example string translation plugins.